# Print all those values of column 'v2' for which 'target' has value= 1 in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the a dataset. It has column named 'target', 'v1' , 'v2' 'v3' ...'v10'. Now I want to print all those values of column 'v2' for which 'target' has value= 1. I have imported this dataset in python using pandas dataframe. What would be the command in python?

Comment: Do you have it in any kind of datastructure, or just as a string?

Comment: I have imported this dataset in python using pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

1) Import the proper modules (should come with your version of python)

```
    import csv
    import re

    infile = 'YOUR PATH AND FILENAME HERE'
```

2) Open the file and create a dictionary of column headers and rows

```
    def open_csv_file(x):
        with open(x, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
            headers = reader.next()
            each_row = list()
            row_list = list()
            for row in reader:
                each_row = (dict(zip(headers, row)))
                row_list.append(each_row)
        return(row_list)
```

3) Create a key list, only selecting the target key (v2)

```
    def process_list(row_list):
        final_list = list()
        for mydictionary in row_list:
            key_list = list()
            subkeys = ["v2"]
        subdict = {x: mydictionary[x] for x in mydictionary if x in subkeys}
        target_values = (subdict.values())
        key_list.append(target_values)
        for item in key_list:
            search_value = item[2] 
            if search_value == '2':
                print(item)
                final_list.append(item)
    return(final_list)
```

4) MAIN FLOW

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
row_list = open_csv_file(infile)
process_list(row_list))
```

Comment: I only realized you have it as pandaframe already -> my functions process regular csv files (in this case, with ; as separator). However, maybe you find this useful nonetheless!

Comment: Later I tried this and it worked:  data['v2'].loc[data['target']==1]